# How Can I insert Multi Record(EX: multi textBox) in Multi fields with just one button?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a Repeater that contain more than 5 rows taken from DB and I wanna Update them with one click , it means the data should send to SQL and each row should save for 1 row to database?

please help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are referring to:

> (...) an easy way to marshal multiple rows of data from a client
>   application to SQL Server without requiring multiple round trips or
>   special server-side logic for processing the data.

If your have at least the SQL Server 2008 version, you can use [Table-Valued Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx). Here is a short tutorial about working with it: [Table Valued Parameters, A Short, Complete Example](http://michaeljswart.com/2011/01/a-short-complete-table-valued-parameter-example/).

For more than 1000 records, also check the other option [Table-Valued Parameters vs. BULK INSERT Operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx#BulkInsert).